# How to add text to curcle avatar

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, image-text

I want to add text to my circle avatar [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knsdj.jpg like this in a row with other avatars.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small custom widget composed of a **Column** widget, containing a **Circle** avatar and a label below, with some spacing in between and padding all around, as in:

```dart
Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
   child: Column(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: [
       CircleAvatar(
         backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1304985167476523008/QNHrwL2q_400x400.jpg"),
         radius: 50,
       ),
       SizedBox(height: 10),
       Container(
         width: 80,
         child: Text('Label for Avatar #$index', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
       )
    ]
  )
)
```

Add it to a **Row** widget and they should look like this;

[image]

Using something like:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: List.generate(
    5, (index) {
        // ... widget code here
    }
  )
)
```